# Qt android screen lock java issue

Tags: android, c++, qt, java-native-interface, qtandroidextras

I have Qt application and need to keep screen from dimming while application is running. I placed following code in the beginning of main() in main.cpp:

```
#ifdef ANDROID
    // disable screen lock on android devices
    QAndroidJniObject activity = QtAndroid::androidActivity();
    if (activity.isValid()) {
        QAndroidJniObject window = activity.callObjectMethod("getWindow", "()Landroid/view/Window;");

        if (window.isValid()) {
            const int FLAG_KEEP_SCREEN_ON = 128;
            window.callMethod<void>("addFlags", "(I)V", FLAG_KEEP_SCREEN_ON);
        }
    }
#endif
```

Which pretty much came from: [How to keep the screen on in Qt for android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27758499/how-to-keep-the-screen-on-in-qt-for-android), except that I use `callMethod<void>` instead of `callObjectMethod`.

Problem is, when application is started, it crashes with huge Java log, I suspect this is relevant part of it:

```
F/art     (26455): art/runtime/runtime.cc:289] Pending exception android.view.ViewRootImpl$CalledFromWrongThreadException thrown by 'unknown throw location'
F/art     (26455): art/runtime/runtime.cc:289] android.view.ViewRootImpl$CalledFromWrongThreadException: Only the original thread that created a view hierarchy can touch its views.
F/art     (26455): art/runtime/runtime.cc:289]   at void android.view.ViewRootImpl.checkThread() (ViewRootImpl.java:6357)
F/art     (26455): art/runtime/runtime.cc:289]   at void android.view.ViewRootImpl.requestLayout() (ViewRootImpl.java:874)
F/art     (26455): art/runtime/runtime.cc:289]   at void android.view.View.requestLayout() (View.java:17476)
F/art     (26455): art/runtime/runtime.cc:289]   at void android.view.View.setLayoutParams(android.view.ViewGroup$LayoutParams) (View.java:11477)
F/art     (26455): art/runtime/runtime.cc:289]   at void android.view.WindowManagerGlobal.updateViewLayout(android.view.View, android.view.ViewGroup$LayoutParams) (WindowManagerGlobal.java:305)
F/art     (26455): art/runtime/runtime.cc:289]   at void android.view.WindowManagerImpl.updateViewLayout(android.view.View, android.view.ViewGroup$LayoutParams) (WindowManagerImpl.java:91)
F/art     (26455): art/runtime/runtime.cc:289]   at void android.app.Activity.onWindowAttributesChanged(android.view.WindowManager$LayoutParams) (Activity.java:2596)
F/art     (26455): art/runtime/runtime.cc:289]   at void org.qtproject.qt5.android.bindings.QtActivity.onWindowAttributesChanged(android.view.WindowManager$LayoutParams) (QtActivity.java:1385)
F/art     (26455): art/runtime/runtime.cc:289]   at void android.view.Window.dispatchWindowAttributesChanged(android.view.WindowManager$LayoutParams) (Window.java:836)
F/art     (26455): art/runtime/runtime.cc:289]   at void com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.dispatchWindowAttributesChanged(android.view.WindowManager$LayoutParams) (PhoneWindow.java:3993)
F/art     (26455): art/runtime/runtime.cc:289]   at void android.view.Window.setFlags(int, int) (Window.java:813)
F/art     (26455): art/runtime/runtime.cc:289]   at void android.view.Window.addFlags(int) (Window.java:771)
```

I added proper permission (android.permission.WAKE_LOCK) to AndroidManifest.xml. Problem seems to be caused by addFlags() being run outside its main view?I googled quite a bit and couldn't find anyone else having the same issue.

Thanks,
Ivan

Comment: Forgot to mention that I use Qt 5.4.0.

Answer (score 2):

```
#if defined(Q_OS_ANDROID)
QAndroidJniObject activity = QtAndroid::androidActivity();
if (activity.isValid()) {
    QAndroidJniObject window = activity.callObjectMethod("getWindow", "()Landroid/view/Window;");

    if (window.isValid()) {
        const int FLAG_KEEP_SCREEN_ON = 128;
        window.callMethod<void>("addFlags", "(I)V", FLAG_KEEP_SCREEN_ON);
    }
    QAndroidJniEnvironment env; if (env->ExceptionCheck()) { env->ExceptionClear(); } //Clear any possible pending exceptions.
}
#endif
```

Got it from [here](https://forum.qt.io/topic/57625/solved-keep-android-5-screen-on/2), works for me on 5.1 android well

Answer (score 1):

I ended up doing this in Java instead.

Here is java code:

```
package org.qtproject.visualization;

import org.qtproject.qt5.android.bindings.*;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.WindowManager;

public class ScreenOnActivity extends QtActivity
{
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        getWindow().addFlags( WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_KEEP_SCREEN_ON );
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    }
}
```

This is then integrated into the rest of application.

Answer (score 0):

When deployed on Android, Qt does not actually run in the main application (Java) thread. As `android.view.Window.addFlags` must be called from Java main thread, it will be hard for you to go back to this thread to have this code work.

The best is to use a `WakeLock` to prevent the system from going to sleep mode. [here is a post explaining how to do it](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34179654/3336423).

This will prevent the screen from dimming while application is running.