# How do I prevent an Android device from going to sleep from Qt application

Tags: android, c++, qt

I'm deploying a Qt application on Android and need to prevent the device from going to standby (else, my threads are interrupted and also my BLE connection gets lost).

I found that on SO: [How do I prevent an Android device from going to sleep programmatically?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3723634/how-do-i-prevent-an-android-device-from-going-to-sleep-programmatically)

This Java code should be executed:

```
PowerManager pm = (PowerManager) getSystemService(Context.POWER_SERVICE);
PowerManager.WakeLock wl = pm.newWakeLock(PowerManager.SCREEN_DIM_WAKE_LOCK, "My Tag");
wl.acquire();

// screen and CPU will stay awake during this section

wl.release();
```

But how to implement that in my Qt application?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

[QAndroidJniObject](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qandroidjniobject.html) helps executing Java code from Qt. Writting it could be hard and it's hard to figure out what's wrong when it does not work....

Here is the solution (encapsulated in a helper class) to lock a `PowerManager.WakeLock` object:

LockHelper.h:

```
#pragma once
#include <QAndroidJniObject>

class KeepAwakeHelper
{
public:
    KeepAwakeHelper();
    virtual ~KeepAwakeHelper();

private:
    QAndroidJniObject m_wakeLock;
};
```

LockHelper.cpp:

```
#include "LockHelper.h"
#include <QAndroidJniObject>
#include <QDebug>
#include "jni.h"

KeepAwakeHelper::KeepAwakeHelper()
{
    QAndroidJniObject activity = QAndroidJniObject::callStaticObjectMethod("org/qtproject/qt5/android/QtNative", "activity", "()Landroid/app/Activity;");
    if ( activity.isValid() )
    {
        QAndroidJniObject serviceName = QAndroidJniObject::getStaticObjectField<jstring>("android/content/Context","POWER_SERVICE");
        if ( serviceName.isValid() )
        {
            QAndroidJniObject powerMgr = activity.callObjectMethod("getSystemService", "(Ljava/lang/String;)Ljava/lang/Object;",serviceName.object<jobject>());
            if ( powerMgr.isValid() )
            {
                jint levelAndFlags = QAndroidJniObject::getStaticField<jint>("android/os/PowerManager","SCREEN_DIM_WAKE_LOCK");

                QAndroidJniObject tag = QAndroidJniObject::fromString( "My Tag" );

                m_wakeLock = powerMgr.callObjectMethod("newWakeLock", "(ILjava/lang/String;)Landroid/os/PowerManager$WakeLock;", levelAndFlags,tag.object<jstring>());
            }
        }
    }

    if ( m_wakeLock.isValid() )
    {
        m_wakeLock.callMethod<void>("acquire", "()V");
        qDebug() << "Locked device, can't go to standby anymore";
    }
    else
    {
        assert( false );
    }
}

KeepAwakeHelper::~KeepAwakeHelper()
{
    if ( m_wakeLock.isValid() )
    {
        m_wakeLock.callMethod<void>("release", "()V");
        qDebug() << "Unlocked device, can now go to standby";
    }
}
```

Then, simply do:

```
{
    KeepAwakeHelper helper;
    // screen and CPU will stay awake during this section
    // lock will be released when helper object goes out of scope
}
```

Note: You need to be sure you have the [WAKE_LOCK](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/Manifest.permission.html#WAKE_LOCK) permission set in your manifest in order to use this code.

Comment: Thank you, very clear and so helpful answer. You can use `Q_ASSERT(false)` instead of `assert(false);`

Answer (score 1):

Another solution:

```
QAndroidJniObject activity = QAndroidJniObject::callStaticObjectMethod("org/qtproject/qt5/android/QtNative", "activity", "()Landroid/app/Activity;");
if (activity.isValid()) {
    QAndroidJniObject window = activity.callObjectMethod("getWindow", "()Landroid/view/Window;");
    if (window.isValid()) {
        const int FLAG_KEEP_SCREEN_ON = 128;
        window.callMethod<void>("addFlags", "(I)V", FLAG_KEEP_SCREEN_ON);
    }
}
```

[Source here](https://forum.qt.io/topic/57625/solved-keep-android-5-screen-on)

I suggest you to read [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5712849/how-do-i-keep-the-screen-on-in-my-app) for educational purpose.

Comment: Saw this topic and could not translate your solution as code using QAndroidJniObject. Nice answer

Answer (score 1):

I used the solution of S.M. Mousavi but the app kept crashing. From the same [source](https://forum.qt.io/topic/57625/solved-keep-android-5-screen-on/6) you have to add some more line of code. Here the complete solution for convenience:

In the .pro file add:

```
QT += androidextras
ANDROID_PERMISSIONS += android.permission.WAKE_LOCK
```

I am not sure that the line concerning the permission is really needed.

In your CCP file:
add these two includes:

```
#include <QAndroidJniObject>
#include <QAndroidJniEnvironment>
```

And where you need:

```
    QAndroidJniObject activity = QAndroidJniObject::callStaticObjectMethod("org/qtproject/qt5/android/QtNative", "activity", "()Landroid/app/Activity;");
            
    if (activity.isValid()) {
        QAndroidJniObject window = activity.callObjectMethod("getWindow", "()Landroid/view/Window;");
        if (window.isValid()) {
             const int FLAG_KEEP_SCREEN_ON = 128;
             window.callMethod<void>("addFlags", "(I)V", FLAG_KEEP_SCREEN_ON);
            
             //Clear any possible pending exceptions.
             QAndroidJniEnvironment env;
             if (env->ExceptionCheck()){
                 env->ExceptionClear();
             }
         }
     }
```